# Vertical print in pdf make library JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

i use pdf make library. can some one say me how to rotate text (elements) using this library?
I want to print pdf vertically.
thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this page on [the documentation](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/document-definition-object/page/) of the pdfmake library

Simply put the option to Portrait

```
pageOrientation: 'portrait'
```

And it should be vertically oriented